# Trace tokes and rules after parser ANTLR 4

Tags: parsing, token, antlr4

I would like to show all tokens and roles that was reached during the parser with Antlr 4, excluding all extra rules on the grammar.

```
    ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(is);
    CerlLexer lexer = new CerlLexer(input);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    CerlParser parser = new CerlParser(tokens);
    ParseTree tree = parser.program();
    System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));
```

Can I do that using Antlr 4 ?

Comment: What do you consider `extra rules on the grammar` to be?

Comment: Points on the tree that are not reached during the execution of some kind of little input.

Answer (score 2):

Set trace to *true* by calling parser method `setTrace()`

```
parser.setTrace(true);
```

It will not print the rules that are not reached.